# mat-select style display default value is block cannot be changed?

Tags: css, angular-material

I am new to angular. Created a header component and in the header I have added another component which is having below code.

```
<mat-form-field class="select-comp">
  <mat-label>Fruits</mat-label>

  <mat-select id="select1" class="item-selector">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [value]="fruit.value">
      {{fruit.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="select-comp">
  <mat-label>Vegitables</mat-label>

  <mat-select id="select2" class="item-selector">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let vegitable of vegitables " [value]="vegitable.value">
      {{vegitable.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select></mat-form-field>
```

if I inspect ".mat-form-field-infix" and ".mat-select-placeholder" css display properties are showing as block , I tried to override it using `display: inline !important`. but it is not working and showing as block in the screen as well the property is block when we inspect. Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: If you use <mat-toolbar> for your header it works perfectly for me. I dont understand your problem 100% to be fair. What you want to see?

Comment: yes using a div first I solved it and later then using <mat-toolbar>. Thank you for your suggestions.